# noVNC "Failed to connect to server" TrueNAS

Tags: novnc

I just installed TrueNAS for the first time to run my NAS, Home Assistant, and hopefully some VMs. (Coming from an old iMac and external hard drives, it's so much better!)

I got Home Assistant working as it automatically sets up a web interface, but there is no VNC connection. In addition, there is no VNC connection to a Windows 11 VM I'm trying to setup.

I came across only a couple online posts about this and they either ended in a private TeamViewer session (for which the solution is not announced) or was told they needed a newer CPU.

I found a post stating that I can check my CPU compatibility by running `grep VT-x /var/run/dmesg.boot`. That returns:

```
VT-x: PAT,HLT,MTF,PAUSE,EPT,UG,VPID
VT-x: PAT,HLT,MTF,PAUSE,EPT,UG,VPID
```

Which to my understanding means it's compatible with bhyve?

Does anybody know why this isn't working?

Thank you!

My specs are:

```
TrueNAS-13.0-RELEASE
Intel Xeon E3-1220 V2
Gen8 HP Microserver
16GB DDR3 1600Mhz Memory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did eventually find the answer. In current versions of TrueNAS, VNC only supports port 5900, which can be set manualy in the devices page for the VM. This is a known bug.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).